# Is There A Good Pseudo Code Editor?

Tags: editor, pseudocode

I have to create some Pseudo Code but want it too "look good" and consistently formatted. Is there something where it will let me make if statements in Pseudo Code (I know it isn't a real language) so that I keep the same syntax throughout?

I don't want to accidentally start using a slightly different syntax as I go along and hence an editor may help me out.

Comment: Since pseudo code isn't a real language you will have a tough time getting syntax highlighting (as there is no syntax to hi light). I would say that you might have some luck just using a normal ide like notepad++ or geany and setting it into some language like python or something and then not being too picky about whether it actually runs. Ie, use the syntax highlighting of a real language but not actually writing in that language.

Comment: in Notepad++, go to Language -> UserDefinedLanguage -> Define your language. There you can configure syntax highlighting for operators, keywords, numbers, and comments. Should be enough for pseudo code. This is relevant in Notepad++ v 7.8.7 in yr 2020

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html) doesn't support Pseudocode out of the box (nor does any other editor AFAIK), but it does have a syntax highlighting editor which you can use to define syntax highlighting and formatting for Pseudocode.

See also http://www.zoovio.com/image/view/2#!prettyPhoto, where Stewart Venit shows the syntax highlighting he wrote for Notepad++ for one of his books.

Comment: http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/